# p. adjust for multiple columns in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r, lapply, p-value

I have a dataframe with hundreds of p values I want to compute FDR significance for.

My dataframe:

```
Trait p-value1 p-value2 p-value3 pvalue4
1 0.5 0.01 0.1 0.12
2 0.1 0.9 0.4 0.32
3 0.2 0.45 0.34 0.45
4 0.2 0.02 0.22 0.11
```

I do it separately for each column with the following script (example on p-value1):

```
fdr <- p.adjust (p-value1, method = "fdr", n = length(p-value1))
```

How can I do it for all columns at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you need not do it for PK i.e. `trait` column. Try this in R version 4.1.0

```
lapply(my_df[-1], \(x) p.adjust (x, method = "fdr", n = length(x)))
```

OR this in older versions

```
lapply(my_df[-1], function(x) p.adjust (x, method = "fdr", n = length(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you also show me how to add the FDR results to the original dataframe? toR_FDR$fdr <- lapply(toR_FDR[-1], function(x) p.adjust (x, method = "fdr", n = length(x))). This is what I normally do, but now I am confused how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%mutate(across(contains("p-value"), ~ p.adjust(.x, method = "fdr", n = length(.x))))
```

If you want new columns but to keep previous columns, you can add a `.names` argument:

```
df%>%mutate(across(contains("p-value"), ~ p.adjust(.x, method = "fdr", n = length(.x)), .names="fdr_{.col}"))
```